# Não estou conseguindo concluir o merge sempre aparece esse erro:

Tags: git, merge, branch

```
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
U       course-git-blog-project
```

Quando eu fiz o merge de um branch deu conflito no código que estava no branch master. Eu corrigir na mão o código, salvei o index.html porem não consigo sair do branch especifico ou fazer o merge da correção do código. Não sei se foi porque eu não alterei para o branch que contia o conflito antes de alterar os erros na mão, porém agora não consigo sair do lugar. 
Não sei se o erro esta na pasta course-git-blog-project que eu deletei em um branch e no master não.

Tela de erro:
[image: Print do erro]

Comment: Depois de editar o arquivo que conflitou, já fez o `git add` dele? E então o `git commit` para terminar o merge?

Comment: Fiz sim e o erro que da é este:
fatal: cannot do a partial commit during a merge.

Comment: Isso é sinal de que você não terminou de resolver todos os conflitos. Como está o `git status`? O que ele mostra de conflitos não resolvidos?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi, usar `git commit -i <file>` daria um jeito mas quando uso, da outro erro.

```$ git commit -i index.html
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
U       course-git-blog-project```

Comment: git status esta assim:

```Wemerson (master *+|MERGING) new-git-project
$ git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:

        deleted:    .gitignore/#course-git-blog-project
        modified:   index.html

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        added by them:   course-git-blog-project

Wemerson (master *+|MERGING) new-git-project
$```

Comment: Será que tenho que add a pasta no starging Index também?

Comment: O 'git status' é foda, cara valeu, tempão quebrando a cabeça aqui, com o problema debaixo do nariz.  o 'git status' me falou o que faltava. Valeu ai.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, como ajudou o colega a resolver o problema dele, sugiro fornecer uma resposta para a pergunta :)

Comment: @Dherik obrigado por lembrar. Vou ver se consigo fazer algo daqui alguns instantes, mas caso queira responder também, fique a vontade.

Comment: o 'git status' estava informando o conflito porém não tinha criado o costume de verificar o staus. Quando olhei lá tinha a resposta. Foi isso que rolou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro indica que você tem ainda um conflito do último merge que precisa ser resolvido.

Para visualizar qual é a situação do seu repositório atual, use o comando:

```
git status
```

Este comando provavelmente irá mostrar o arquivo em conflito `course-git-blog-project`. Abra o arquivo, encontre o ponto de conflito, faça a edição do arquivo para ficar da forma que deve ficar, e resolva o conflito com:

```
git add course-git-blog-project
```

Depois disto, você pode executar o comando `git commit` que o Git abrirá uma confirmação da mensagem de commit para resolução do conflito.